# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date Exception while converting timestamp value to time in java

Tags: java, timestamp, deprecated, simpledateformat

I want to convert a Timestamp value which is passed as String to SimpleDateFormat Object into Time Value but it throws a Unparseable date exception.

```
The Value which i am passing is Thu Jan 1 17:45:00 UTC+0530 1970
```

Bur i am getting an Exception as mentioned below:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 1 17:45:00 UTC+0530 1970"
```

Please find the below code which i have implemented(Not Working):

```
static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
static SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
static SimpleDateFormat outputFormatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

public static String convertUtcDateStringToTime(String utcDateValue) throws Exception
    {
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(utcDateValue);
        String returnDate=outputFormatTime.format(inputFormat.parse(parsedDate.toString()));
        return returnDate;
    }
```

If i use the below code it works fine for me(Working) but its a depreciated function of Date which i want to avoid..

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static String convertUtcDateStringToTime(String utcDateValue) throws Exception
{
    Date dateValue=new Date(utcDateValue);
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateValue.toString());
    String returnDate=outputFormatTime.format(inputFormat.parse(parsedDate.toString()));
    return returnDate;
}
```

Please Guide Me To implement the logic where i have missed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your 2nd `SimpleDateFormat` object, is not needed at all. You are doing the extra work, which is not needed. So, remove this variable:

```
static SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);  // Not needed.
```

Secondly [`DateFormat#format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) methods takes a `Date` object. You are passing it a `String`. That wouldn't work. That is why you don't need the above object. There is no need to do a `inputFormat.parse(parsedDate.toString())` again.

---

Now, the format to parse your current string should be:

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'z yyyy"
```

You need to give the `UTC` in quotes, before `z`. Or for more general case:

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy"
```

So, your code should be like:

```
static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.US);
static SimpleDateFormat outputFormatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

public static String convertUtcDateStringToTime(String utcDateValue) throws Exception
    {
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(utcDateValue);
        String returnDate=outputFormatTime.format(inputFormat);
        return returnDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

with an addition to the answers if the formatting string is like this

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
```

then your input string should be

```
"Thu Jan 1 17:45:00 +0530 1970"
```

note that the "UTC" is skipped as implicitly it refers to the [**RFC 822 time zone**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone)

Answer (score 1):

You input `dateformat` needs to be

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.US);
```

The other formatting is all upto, you based on your requirements.